# How to hardcode bash script in python file

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a python tool that makes some processing, data gathering and eventually calling a bash scripts via `subprocess`.

The tricky part of my tool is: I use nuitka to compile python files to the single binary file. I'm doing this because I don't want my users to add any features plus I'd like my tool to be mysterious.

The problem is of course, what to do with that bash scripts. For now, I store them together with my nuitka-ed binary. However, due to above, I don't want a bash scripts to be that easily accessible.

For now, I can see two options for me:

1. I can compile `*.sh` files and link them with nuitka-ed binary.
2. I can hardcode `*.sh` files in `*.py` files.

Option `1` is rather not an option due to its complexity. Option `2` is slightly better, but for now, my best solutions is following:

I make `script.py`:

```
"""
#!/bin/bash

ls -alh /var
echo $?
# (...)
"""
```

And I inject `script.__doc__` to the `subprocess.Popen(['bash(...)`.

Is there any better - more elegant way to achieve my goal while maintaining bash script readability ?

Comment: I don't know whether your script is representative of what you're trying to do, but that functionality can easily be implemented in Python... see `os.listdir()` or possibly the `glob` module. Since you want to prevent inspection/modification of the shell script, what benefit is there to writing it in bash, why not just implement it in Python?

Comment: A user could still run `strace` or `ltrace` on your program to see the calls being made.  Scripts embedded in strings in a program can be found using `strings(1)`.  If a user is determined enough, and they have read access to your files, there isn't much you can do other than obfuscation and forget about using bash.

Comment: My bash script is over 200 lines long, so not-hardcoding is not an option. Speaking `strace`, `ltrace`, `strings` whatever, I know user may do it, but we talk about internal, corporate tool, so users are enough lazy to not dive into binary.

Answer (score 0):

To hardcode bash-code within a python file you could do it this way.

```
import subprocess
import StringIO

# In Python
text = "foobar"

your_bash_cmd = "echo "+text
process = subprocess.Popen([your_bash_cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
your_bash_output = process.stdout.read()

# Process bash output in python
print(your_bash_output)
```